# export mail to single text file using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

How do I export all emails in Inbox  of outlook  to a single text file? 
As of now I have code which will export mails to a text file but each mails are saved in separate text files. I need in single text file

```
Sub saveEmailTxt()
Dim objItem As Object 

Dim iCount As Integer 'iterate over all Items in the current folder and save the body as textfile in c:\' 

For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items 
objItem.SaveAs "C:\Mail" & CStr(iCount) & ".txt", olSaveAsText 
iCount = iCount + 1 
Next 

End Sub
```

This is my previous code which will save into text file, but it will create separate text files for each mail.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Perhaps opening the text file for Appending might help?  Without showing your code, help might not come easily.

Comment: Sub saveEmailTxt()
Dim objItem As Object
Dim iCount As Integer

'iterate over all Items in the current folder and save the body as textfile in c:\'

For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items
objItem.SaveAs "C:\Mail" & CStr(iCount) & ".txt", olSaveAsText
iCount = iCount + 1
Next

End Sub                                                                                                                                         This is my previous code which will save into textfile, but it will create separate text file for each mail, i need to save all in single text file

Comment: You are explicitly writing to a new filename: objItem.SaveAs "C:\Mail" & CStr(iCount).  So Mail1, Mail2, Mail3, etc.  You can try removing that part, but I suspect it might overwrite each time.

Comment: Andrew  can u give me the exact code. Some how it is required very urgent...!

Comment: Try this:  objItem.SaveAs "C:\Mail.txt", olSaveAsText as I mentioned, it might overwrite the file each time, but I didn't test it.

Comment: Ya its overwriting the file itself. Can u help me to write all mails in single file. It will be very much needful.

Comment: Put the code at back to the way you have it.  You have two choices in approach methods: call a bat file to concatenate the files after they are written, OR, add a second sub routine to the script that uses FileScriptingObject: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/12/01/can-i-combine-multiple-text-files-using-a-script.aspx